# How do you defeat the revenants in the Brecilian Forest?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

The first time I tried to take them on I was only level 10. Now I returned at level 14 with more tricks up my sleeve and I still can't beat them. They seem to be completely immune to all magic so I can't even CC them. Every spell I cast at them - hexes, stuns, prisons - don't affect them at all.

How do you go by and kill them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have some really heavy health and a ton of resistances. I used my Level 11 Warden (rogue) to backstab then stealth, backstab then stealth until he was at about half health.

Then I charged my tank in and I kept backstabbing. I had Morrigan and Wynne healing as best they could and just winded him down. It takes a bit, but it can be done.

If you're a mage, I suggest using a similar tactic, but focus on healing your tank and doing as much damage as possible when he is okay.

Answer (score 6):

I believe I have devised the best strategy for revenant killing:

- Revenents are **immune to cold damage**, but you could still **freeze them solid** with **cone of cold**.
- The **revival ability** in **spirit healer** is **invaluable** when defeating them, so **take Wynne along**.
- **Sten is quite effective** but he **dies easily**. Bump up his **constitution**.
- **Kill the skeletons first** so that you can **focus all your power on the revenant**.

Remember to do the elven ritual with the stolen book (from dalish) and tablet (in the ruin) to get the juggernaut plate.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question here is my tactic to go without loosing any party member (normal difficulty). I had 3 mages (me, Morrigan, Wynn) and Leliana with bow.

- First I cast **Force Field** on him to deal with skeletons without his interference (me and Morrigan both know it so at least one always was successfull)
- Deal with skeletons;
- Cast Misdirection Hex on revenant. If he is left alone then he won't be able to do any damage to you (except very rare critical hits and pull/mass pull which in my opinion he casts only after being disabled for some time)

So if two of your mages have both **Force Field** and **Misdirection Hex** then generally you can keep him from attacking you indefinitey. Also **Force Field** could be used to give you some time to wait for other abilities to get off cooldown